# SQL Server 2012 generate multiple columns from three depend on serial number

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2012: I have a table that contains 3 columns and 30 rows, as shown in the first screenshot:

[image: first image]

I need to divide the rows after serial 10 to another columns as shown in the second screenshot:

[image: Second image]

Comment: can you add DDL for your table and insert data script.

Comment: Read this on why images are discouraged:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: please read this (https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to improve question

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with subqueries and joins:

```
SELECT sub.*,
sub2.SN1 AS SN2, sub2.MPType1 AS MPType2, sub2.MPTrade1 AS MPTrade2,
sub3.SN1 AS SN3, sub3.MPType1 AS MPType3, sub3.MPTrade1 AS MPTrade3
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM t
 WHERE SN1 < 11) sub
INNER JOIN
(SELECT *
 FROM t
 WHERE SN1 BETWEEN 11 AND 20) sub2
ON sub.SN1 + 10 = sub2.SN1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT *
 FROM t
 WHERE SN1 > 20) sub3
ON sub2.SN1 + 10 = sub3.SN1
```